# Factory vs Multipurpose constructor for creating object on event

Tags: javascript, events, design-patterns, module

I have two "modules" `PanelManager` and `Panel` which I want to be as independent as possible so I use `events` for communication between them. This way you can run each module independently on if the other one is running and you can plug or unplug modules dinamically just setting or removing the listeners.

The `PanelManager` module dispatches a `newPanel` event whenever it needs a new panel, and listens for `newPanelCreated` events.

The `Panel` module listens for the `newPanel` events, creates a new Panel and dispatches a `newPanelCreated` custom event with the new panel as `{detail}`.

To achive this I can design the `Panel` module in two different ways: the first is a `PanelFactory` class that sets the listeners when instantiated and creates instances of a `Panel` class. The second is just one `Panel` class with a flag in the constructor so if it's instantiated with a `true` flag it just sets the listeners, but if instantiated with a `false` flag it acts as a regular `Panel`. This way the same class could act as *Factory* and *Panel* at the same time.

Which approach would you recommend? Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would not use a flag parameter for the constructor (after all, constructors are supposed to be free of side effects) and not use a separate factory class either.

Instead, create a method on the `Panel` class that initialises your listeners. In the `newPanel` handler, just invoke the constructor and then that method.
Alternatively, make it static method like `Panel.createWithListeners` that does call the constructor and then sets up the listeners. This has the advantage that you can't accidentally call the init method multiple times on the same instance.

Or you drop the method altogether and just set up the listeners directly from the `newPanel` event, after all this event code is the (only?) interface between the `Panel` class and the event bus so it should be in one place.